# Minecraft keeps crashing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-8

My sister and I recently upgraded to Windows 8, and yesterday we were playing Minecraft like normal. Then all of a sudden we got this pop-up for Java. I clicked on the popup, then I got kicked out of the LAN and she couldn't join mine so we restored our computers back to when Minecraft would let us play together.

So we uninstalled java, and re-installed Java 6. It worked for her and when I went to open a single-player map and it froze. I tried opening Magic-launcher, and it would load the map but I would constantly lag then finally crash.

**Update:**

- When I say restored I mean I backed up to an earlier date.
- I have no mods installed

The popup asked if I wanted to do something like share my java with public. When she opened her LAN when we got them working I clicked no because when I clicked accept it wouldn't let me join her LAN

Comment: Did you have mods installed before you downgraded to Windows 8 that you don't have now? If so, that could be why it doesn't work.

Comment: What was in the popup?  Why did you choose JRE6 versus JRE7? 32-bit or 64-bit? There's a lot of missing information.

Comment: wen i say restored i mean went backed up to an  earlyer date and no i had no mods and and the popup sead it asked if i wanted to do something like share my java with public when she opend her LAN when we got them working i clicked no becouse when i clicked accept it woldent let me join her LAN

Comment: @killkid135 You mean you told Windows to deny Java internet access?

Comment: You say you have no mods now. But, did you have mods *before* on that same map it crashes on now?

Comment: yes and no abought the mods i had made a new .minecraft and a new map and it freezes

Comment: There are like three or four independent variables here. You're going to have to narrow it down to one problem before we can diagnose this. You could first fix your Java's access to the Internet (you should have picked "yes"—not being able to join her LAN game is a separate problem that has nothing to do with that popup). You could also make sure you have Java 7 64-bit installed. (6 is outdated, and 7 plays nice with Minecraft now.) Then see how it's working, and update this question.

Comment: As SevenSidedDie pointed out, this question does not have enough information to be answered and should be closed as "too broad"

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not work because Java can have some weird issues, but this solves 99% of most issues. First, go to Add or Remove Programs (or it's equivalent in Windows 8, I don't know what they renamed it to) and delete everything related to Java. Next, go [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp) and redownload Java 7 (try the 64-bit version, if you use a 32-bit browser grab the 32-bit version) and reinstall it. Then follow [these directions](http://p.defau.lt/?MAnn3k0TTd3_St_RecbFzw) to set up the regular Java-based launcher. Fire it up and try playing a single-player map, and report back with any issues.

Comment: To open Add or Remove programs in windows 8, open the start screen, type (don't click on anything) add or remove programs, and then (for windows 8.1 (and possibly windows 8) change the search type from everywhere to settings, and click the icon with the box with the CD in the front of it.